# Por qué me devuelve un array vacío el preg_split()

Tags: php, regex

Tengo esta cadena

```
$userinfo = '<div class="container">
                <div class="hijo">
                    <?php echo $cabecera[1]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="hijo">
                    <?php echo $cabecera[2]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="hijo">
                    <?php echo $cabecera[3]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                </div>
            </div>';
```

Y quiero obtener solo el codigo HTML, pero me devuelve un array vacio. La expresión regular que estoy usando es esta `/<\?php(.*)\?>/`.

```
    <?php
   $userinfo = '<div class="container">
                    <div class="hijo">
                        <?php echo $cabecera[1]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">
                        <?php echo $cabecera[2]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">
                        <?php echo $cabecera[3]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>';

   $arreglo = preg_split('/<\?php(.*)\?>/', $userinfo);

   print_r($arreglo);

?>
```

**Lo que espero obtener es esto:**

```
    Array ( 
         [0] =><div class="container">
         <div class="hijo">

         [1] =>   </div>
         <div class="hijo">

         [2] => </div>
         <div class="hijo">

         [3] =></div>
         </div>
```

**Esto es lo que obtengo**

```
    Array ( [0] =>
[1] =>
[2] =>
[3] =>
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El `print_r` devuelve esto: `Array
(
    [0] => <div class="container">
                    <div class="hijo">
                        
    [1] => 
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">
                        
    [2] => 
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">
                        
    [3] => 
                    </div>
                </div>
)`, ¿por qué dices que devuelve un array vacío?

Comment: No sé que puedo hacer. Pero lo bueno es que hay valores en el array como me dices :)

Comment: No sé mucho de REGEX, pero la expresión que estás usando parece que lo que pide es que te quite el contenido con etiqueta PHP. Lo que esperas obtener no coincide con esa intención, por ejemplo, ¿de dónde sale esto: `<div class="son">`? No se ve en tu código HTML. Además, extraer texto HTML con expresiones regulares es siempre inseguro y muy sometido a errores. ¿Por qué te has visto obligado a hacer esto? ¿No hay otra forma de resolver tu problema?

Comment: Ya arregle el código. Simplemente estoy practicando, soy nuevo en PHP. Por si acaso tendrás otra manera de solucionarlo?, ya que según tu comentario me estas diciendo que estoy realizando malas prácticas.

Comment: He visto que por experiencia usar REGEX para parsear contenido HTML no es siempre exacto, debido en gran parte a que un HTML puede tener una forma de escritura irregular, puede tener varias clases, por ejemplo: `<div class="abuelo padre"></div>` y esa misma situación se puede expresar al revés: `<div class="padre abuelo"></div>` Esos dos `div` para HTML son exactamente lo mismo, pero para REGEX no. Y así muchas cosas más. ¿Quieres otras vías de solución? Quizá podamos sugerir alguna, pero se necesita partir de un problema concreto. ¿Cuál es el problema a solucionar?

Comment: He creado una página en donde el administrador puede crear acordeones y colocar preguntas dentro de estas. El punto es que cuando le de a guardar, todo el script se guarde en la base de datos. Ya de ahí lo usuarios podrán visualizar los cambios.

Comment: Ese script tambien viene acompañado de codigo PHP, y eso tambien lo estaria guardado. Pero algunos ya me habian recomendado que es preligroso.

Comment: Claro que es hiper peligroso. ¿Por qué no creas un formulario donde cada usuario escriba los datos, guardas esos datos y en base a ellos generas lo que haga falta. Sería cuestión de guardar los componentes simplemente en la BD y el contenido lo creas de forma dinámica.

Comment: Es una gran idea, pero primero me gustaría terminar esta duda que tengo. Ya que es un poco extraño que no me salga y a ti si. ¿Crees que sea por mi versión de PHP? Mi versión es 7.3.1

Comment: No creo que sea por eso. Probé el código en [rextester](https://rextester.com), que usa PHP 7. Puedes probarlo ahí en línea. O si quieres dale a [edit] para que pongas el código completo tal y como lo tienes. No hay motivo para que te dé un array vacío.

Comment: Tienes razón, sí funciona. ¿Pero por qué razón en mi código no funciona? Yo probé mi código en https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_webview_online.php y tampoco funciono. Si no fuera molestia, podrías probar mi código ahí.

Comment: Te voy a dar un consejo, si quieres ahorrar muchas horas de depuración, en vez de `echo` o `print_r` usa siempre **`var_dump`**. Ahí podrás ver la longitud de los valores y saber que algo pasa. Cuando pruebo el código con `var_dump` en tutorialspoint no veo en efecto los `div`, pero me dice que las cadenas tienen tamaño, no están vacías... Entonces, ¿por qué no se ven?, porque la salida está *parseada*  a HTML y como los `divs` no tienen datos no se ve nada. Pruébalo así y verás que ahora se ve: **`echo "<pre>";foreach ($arreglo as $row){
    echo htmlspecialchars($row);
}echo "</pre>";`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu variable `$arreglo` no es ni muchos menos un array vacío como crees. Habrás pasado horas rompiéndote el coco de por qué no se ve nada y todo porque no has usado al mejor amigo que tienes en PHP para la depuración, que se llama `var_dump`.

Si pones esto en tu programa:

```
var_dump($arreglo);
```

Verás esto en pantalla:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(87) "



                        "
  [1]=>
  string(92) "





                        "
  [2]=>
  string(92) "





                        "
  [3]=>
  string(50) "



"
}
```

Claro claro, se ve todo en blanco, pero los valores del array tienen datos, observa que dice `string(N)`, donde `N` es la longitud de cada valor. Hay datos, pero, ¿por qué no se ven?

Muy sencillo, porque el contenido es renderizado a HTML y como lo que hay son divs sin nada escrito, por eso no se ve nada en pantalla.

Si pruebas así por ejemplo verás datos:

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($arreglo as $row){
    echo htmlspecialchars($row);
}
echo "</pre>";
```

**Salida:**

```
<div class="container">
                    <div class="hijo">

                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">

                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

Si pruebas el código en rextester, que no renderiza a HTML, verás bien el resultado del `var_dump`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(87) "<div class="container">
                    <div class="hijo">
                        "
  [1]=>
  string(92) "
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">
                        "
  [2]=>
  string(92) "
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">
                        "
  [3]=>
  string(50) "
                    </div>
                </div>"
}
```

Y el `print_r` también se ve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <div class="container">
                    <div class="hijo">

    [1] => 
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">

    [2] => 
                    </div>

                    <div class="hijo">

    [3] => 
                    </div>
                </div>
)
```

#### Conclusión

Siempre que vayas a depurar, usa `var_dump`

Comment: Lección aprendida y gracias por el consejo!!! :) Aunque si use el var_dump y note la cantidad de String, pero pense que era un error que cometi. Nunca creí que la respuesta ya la tenia. Pero quisiera saber bien esta parte que dices: "porque la salida está parseada a HTML y como los divs no tienen datos no se ve nada." ¿No entiendo muy bien cuando dice que la salida estaba parseada a HTML? Osea que si quiero mostrar codigo HTML es necesario que NO lo parsee?

Comment: No es exactamente eso lo que quise decir. Generalmente para el usuario final el contenido HTML se presenta renderizado (o parseado, término inglés), solo que en este caso, como eran divs vacíos no se veía nada. Ahora si es contenido para un curso HTML por ejemplo donde interesa mostrar el código interno, entonces no deberías renderizar el HTML porque lo que interesa es precisamente mostrar las etiquetas HTML y demás.